# How to write value to an input type = file of an form using php

Tags: html

I am able to write value  to  an input t form type= text

for ex

```
 <input type="text" value="xyz">
```

But what i want is, to write a value to input type="file" . I have tried the code below  but it's not working.

```
 <input type="file" value="something">
```

Comment: <input type="file" name="fileName" value="C:/hello world/test.txt" size=80>

Answer (score 7):

You cannot, for fairly obvious security reasons.

If a webpage could specify a default value for a file input, then it could (for example) specify `c:\place\where\finance\software\stores\accounts\by\default` (and then use JavaScript to submit the form without the user having to do anything).

Answer (score 0):

PHP aside, HTML doesn't let you assign values to `input type="file"` elements as a security measure. If HTML had this power, you could setup several of these fields and point each one to a windows file on the user's computer. The result would be a victim submitting a form with no idea they were also submitting sensitive information. No JavaScript is required. The victim might submit such a form to log in or post a comment on a blog somewhere.  Why wouldn't the victim notice they are also submitting a file? CSS can style such elements offscreen using negative coordinates so its a lot like an `input type="hidden"`, just in this case it would submitting a file instead.